# Копирование\вставка в Git Shell на Windows 7

Tags: windows, git, github

Возможно ли? Привык писать все руками, вводить каждый раз длиннющий путь к репозиторию, равно как и пихать все в корень С, не хочется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правой клавишей на хедере окна:
edit -> mark, copy, paste

Ну или через shift + insert.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно добавить путь к git-у в PATH и дальше работать в PowerShell или cmd. Но проще, как мне кажется, использовать SourceTree от Bitbucket (требует регистрации на их сайте).